# Cloning a CSS Design from a button by not using developer tools

Tags: css

I got a picture of a nice looking button and I want to get the CSS of it. Sadly, I just got the picture of the button.

[image: btn]

So when trying to rebuild this I struggle with the box shadows. I need an inner shadow and an outer shadow, no?

This is what I got so far

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial";
  background-color: gray;
}

#box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-color: #99ff99;
  background: linear-gradient(#262626, #00b33c);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -7px 7px #99ff99;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  TEST AGAIN
</div>
```

Well my current button looks really ugly, I hope some of you could help me out. Maybe I just need the outer shadows and some color changes ..

Comment: Just a note that I instantly recognized this button as coming from [speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net). It comes from what they are now calling the legacy site because they have a new beta site running. So if you want to inspect the button in the console, make sure you're at speedtest.net and not beta.speedtest.net, and then run the test, and at the end you'll see the "Test Again" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the effect, you can actually stack `box-shadows`. Also, don't be afraid to play around with the opacity of the shadow colors using `rgba` values:

CSS:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial";
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height:3;
}

#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-color: #99ff99;
  background: linear-gradient(#262626, #00b33c);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -7px 7px rgba(255,255,255, .2), 0 0px 4px #fff, 0px 0px 15px #00b33c;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  TEST AGAIN
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lby8w1h8/1/

Edit: box-shadows stack in the order they are listed...so the first will be on top, the second below that, the third below, etc.

Comment: That's it, some changes and I got it :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a `dropshadow`. I tried to recreate the button a little bit, but you might want to adjust it on your own as well.

[Here is the link](https://jsfiddle.net/fz0qbbo3/1/).

CSS:

```
#box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-color: #99ff99;
  background: linear-gradient(#262626, #00b33c);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 7px #99ff99;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.80));
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 231, 255, 0.8))
}
```